# Adjusting bootstrap jumbotron background image to avoid collision with text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jumbotron with background image and text. I need to have the image adjust so that the text does not collide with any part of the background image.

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Header title text</h1>
    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff url("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ftp-assets/family.png") center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

p {
  margin-left: -2%;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:https://jsfiddle.net/2ek2e2rf/**

Comment: Why not just move the text outside of the jumbotron since the background image basically takes up the entire height of the container? https://jsfiddle.net/2ek2e2rf/1/

Comment: The image needs to stay completely visible while the window is being reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to something like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-dark">
    <div class="jumbotron-background">
        <img src="assets/background_img4.jpg" class="blur ">
    </div>
    <div class="container text-white" style="background-color: transparent; border: none;">
        <h1>Some text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, you can adjust the background by changing the following properties:

```
.jumbotron-background {
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
```